# Convert HTACCESS mod_rewrite directives to nginx format?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I'm brand new to nginx and I am trying to convert the app I wrote over from Apache as I need the ability to serve a lot of clients at once without a lot of overhead! I'm getting the hang of setting up nginx and FastCGI PHP but I can't wrap my head around nginx's rewrite format just yet. I know you have to write some simple script that goes in the server {} block in the nginx config but I'm not yet familiar with the syntax. Could anyone with experience with both Apache and nginx help me convert this to nginx format? Thanks!

```
# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# Rewrite from canonical domain (remove www.)            #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# This redirects index.php to /                          #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(index|index\.php)\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(index|index\.php)$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L] 

# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# This rewrites 'directories' to their PHP files,        #
# fixes trailing-slash issues, and redirects .php        #
# to 'directory' to avoid duplicate content.             #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^.]+\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# ------------------------------------------------------ #
# If it wasn't redirected previously and is not          #
# a file on the server, rewrite to image generation      #
# ------------------------------------------------------ #

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-@#\ "'\+]+)/?([a-z0-9_\-]+)?(\.png|/)?$ generation/image.php?user=${escapemap:$1}&template=${escapemap:$2} [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

I convert part-by-part to follow more easily.

Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;

    rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(index|index\.php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(index|index\.php)$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Nginx:

```
location = /index {
    try_files $uri @homepage;
}
location @homepage {
    rewrite ^ http://domain.com break;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_uri ~* /index\.php$) {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com break;
    }
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    error_page 404 /error/404.php;
}
```

Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^.]+\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Nginx:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

if (-f $document_root/$request_uri.php) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    if (-f $document_root/$request_uri) {
        rewrite ^([^.]+)\.php$ http://domain.com$1 permanent;
    }
    ...
}
```